# How to avoid duplication and to fetch the child class records based on max value in HQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

Hql  query that I am currently using is

```
from ListAssessImpl x left join fetch x.reviews r where x.site in 
(:currentSearchSite) and x.status = :status and 1=1 order by x.score
desc, x.name asc
```

ListAssessImpl and  reviews is one to many , multiple records in reviews based on ListAssessImpl Id.

How can I modify the query If i have to get only the max value from review based on ListAssessImpl.

I tried to do with Max() , but didn't work, I am using Hibernate 3 and spring 2.5

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(r.value) from ListAssessImpl x left join x.reviews r
where x.site in (:currentSearchSite) and x.status = :status
```

Comment: What if I have to fetch records from ListAssessImpl and its corresponding Records in review with Max of Id.

Comment: Then, just readjust the query to consider all of the necessary information.